# Cards on amazon alexa skill enabled devices without screen

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have created an Alexa Skill using ASK sdk version 2 for Node.js. I have used standard card's at various places in my skill. But the problem is that I do not have alexa enabled device with screen. These cards are displayed when I test the skill using the Test button inside the developer portal.

What tool should I be using to display these cards ? I do have an alexa app on my mobile.

Thanks

Comment: You can use echo spot, otherwise there is no way to get proper display of the card

Comment: can we link an account and send the card to the user ?

Answer (score 3):

At time of writing, if your Echo device doesn't have a screen, then the only other place card objects of `"type": "Standard",` or `"type": "Simple",` will appear is in the Alexa app under "More > Activity History" like so:

**Skill Response Card Object:**

```
"card": {
    "type": "Simple",
    "title": "Home Card Test",
    "content": "This is a 'Simple' card."
},
```

**Alexa App Experience:**
[image]